# What is wrong with this mail header text?

Tags: php, email, mime, email-attachments

The following $header is being sent via PHP's `mail($to,$subject,$content,$header)` command. The mail arrives and appears to have an attachment. But the mail text is empty as is the file.  I think this has something to do with line spacing but I can't see the problem. I have tried putting the contents (between the boundaries) in `$contents` rather than appending it to `$header`.  It doesn't make a difference.  Any thoughts?

```
From: dnagirl@someplace.com 
Reply-To: dnagirl@someplace.com 
X-Mailer: PHP 5.3.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="7425195ade9d89bc7492cf520bf9f33a"

--7425195ade9d89bc7492cf520bf9f33a
Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

this is a test message.

--7425195ade9d89bc7492cf520bf9f33a
Content-Type: application/pdf; name="test.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjMKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29k
ZT4+CnN0cmVhbQp4nE2PT0vEMBDFadVdO4p/v8AcUyFjMmma5CqIIF5cctt6WnFBqLD1+4Np1nY3
c3lvfm+GyQ4VaUY11iQ2PTyuHG5/Ibdx9fIvhi3swJMZX24c602PTzENegwUbNAO4xcoCsG5xuWE
.
... the rest of the file
.
MDAwMDA2MDYgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDcwNyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMDY4IDAwMDAwIG4g
CjAwMDAwMDA2NDcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDY3NyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAxMjg2IDAwMDAw
IG4gCjAwMDAwMDA5MzIgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PCAvU2l6ZSAxNCAvUm9vdCAxIDAgUiAv
SW5mbyAyIDAgUgovSUQgWzxEMURDN0E2OUUzN0QzNjI1MDUyMEFFMjU0MTMxNTQwQz48RDFEQzdB
NjlFMzdEMzYyNTA1MjBBRTI1NDEzMTU0MEM+XQo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDY5MwolJUVPRgo=


--7425195ade9d89bc7492cf520bf9f33a--
```

`$header` ends without a line break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the code below to send a message with an attachment as well as html and text message parts. I remember fighting with it a long time to get it right, but unfortunately don't remember which parts were my problems. Maybe looking at it will help you out. I've changed some irrelevant variables and hopefully made it easier to read. Feel free to ask if something is weird or unclear and I'll try to explain.

```
public function sendEmail($htmlString)
{
    $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));

    $message = "--mixed-$random_hash\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alt-' . $random_hash . '"' . "\n\n";
    $message .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
    $message .= '--alt-' . $random_hash . "\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' . "\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\n\n";

    // text message
    $message .= strip_tags($htmlString) . "\n\n";

    $message .= '--alt-' . $random_hash . "\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"' . "\n";
    $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit' . "\n\n";

    // html message
    $message .= $htmlString . "\n\n";

    $message .= '--alt-' . $random_hash . '--' . "\n";

    // graph image
    if($this->selectedGraph != 0)
    {
        $graphString = $this->getGraph(); // image attachment
        $graphString = chunk_split(base64_encode($graphString));

        $linkID = 'graph-' . $userInfo['FirmID'] . $random_hash . '-image';

        $message .= '--mixed-' . $random_hash . "\n";
        $message .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
        $message .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\n";
        $message .= 'Content-ID: ' . $linkID . "\n";
        $message .= 'Content-Type: image/gif; name="graph.gif"' . "\n";
        $message .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment' . "\n\n";

        $message .= $graphString;
        $message .= '--mixed-' . $random_hash . '--' . "\n";

    }
    else
    {
        $message .= '--mixed-' . $random_hash . '--' . "\n";
    }


    $headers = 'From: ' . $this->from. "\r\nReply-To: " . $this->replyto;
    $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"mixed-" . $random_hash . "\"\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0";

    $flags = '-f ' . BOUNCED_EMAIL_ADDRESS;

    return mail($userInfo['Email'], $this->subject, $message, $headers, $flags);

}
```

Comment: I changed my line endings from \r\n to \n based on your example.  That fixed it.  Tx!

Comment: Line endings were going to be my suggestion but I was late :) The right format is \r\n but in my experience there're some e-mail server programs out there that try to fix it themselves and finally break messages.

Answer (score 0):

These things happen when building mime mails from scratch. There are a couple of php modules you can use to generate cool and compatible mime messages. [Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) should do the trick.